# How can I make a bone or object slowly follow behind another? (Automating behavior of a camera drone)

Tags: animation, rigging, physics

I’m rigging a character with a drone that follows behind them.

[image: Character to be rigged]

I’d like to have the drone automatically float to a fixed point behind the character. The goal is not to have it simply lagging behind the torso’s rotation and position, as if attached by a spring bone, but always attempting to return to the fixed point *as the crow flies* with speed increasing based on distance from the point. If possible I’d also like to be able to:

- Control the maximum “pursuit speed” at which the drone returns to that point
- Make manual keyframe adjustments to its path after the fact
- Separately maintain and/or simulate the orientation and self righting behavior of the drone

I’ve made two rough maquettes using cubes and keyframe animation of the kind of effect I’d like to achieve automatically. The first is the basic idea, the second is with the additional behaviors.

[image: Maquette]

[image: Maquette2]

I know the fixed point will likely be its own bone parented to the root of the whole character armature, but I’m not sure how to approach making the drone follow it. What combinations of bone/object constraints, physics simulation, etc., might be used to achieve this?

Comment: You can use a cloth simulation and a pin group with the weight being above 0 and below 1, to have it follow a point dynamically.

Comment: There are also the two addons [Spring Bones](https://github.com/artellblender/springbones) and [Wiggle Bones](https://blenderartists.org/t/wiggle-bones-a-jiggle-bone-implementation-for-2-8/1154726) that might help to achieve this. I'm not sure if they work in the latest Blender version (3.3)